# parseInt last number and save as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, parseint

I want to save two different vales as two variables from an image counter class like:

```
<div class="counter">33 / 111</div>
```

33 is the number of current image.

111 are the images in total.

I can get the first value with parseInt and save it in a variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var sc=$('.counter').text();

    sc=parseInt(sc);
    alert(sc);


});
```

But how can I get the last number (the total number of images = "111") and put it in another second variable?

```
var x=$('.counter').text();

    x=???parseInt(x)+???;//get the last Number (111)
    alert(x); //x=111
```

Comment: Maybe you could split the string against the delimiter somehow. I would investigate that strategy.

Comment: On second thought, don't investigate anything, it's not worth it. You already have three answers that go into JavaScript 101 for you. Oh how low we have fallen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `parseInt()` to get the first value. Use `split()` to get the values into an array, and then you can grab them from the array, like so:

```
var values = $('.counter').text().split('/');
```

And then to get them into separate variables, you can simply reference the relevant index of the array:

```
var firstValue = values[0];
var secondValue = values[1];
```

#### NOTE

---

The above solution will return the string values from the div, so if you actually need them as integers, you can convert them separately with `parseInt()` like so:

```
var firstValue = parseInt(values[0]);
var secondValue = parseInt(values[1]);
```

Or you can convert the entire array to integers before you assign your `firstValue` and `secondValue` variables, and not have to use `parseInt()` in your declarations, like so:

```
var values = $('.counter').text().split('/').map(Number);
```

#### ANOTHER NOTE

---

If you're using the new ES6 specification for JavaScript (which has a ton of goodies in it), you can actually do this as a pretty slick one-liner, like so:

```
let [firstValue, secondValue] = $('.counter').text().split('/').map(Number);
```

Comment: Don't forget to parseInt(values[n]) to make sure it returns a number and not a string :)

Comment: @jjr2000, thank you for pointing out the upvotes here are not rational. This is actually detrimental to the questioner since they want a number as the output. Meet the new Stack Overflow: Wrong answers to bad questions™.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi apparently you haven't noticed that the OP makes no mention of what they actually want to do with these values. For all we know the OP *wants* strings, not integers. I'll let them make that decision instead of forcing it upon them. The OP only asks how to get at those values - this answer (and actually the other answers as well) gives them exactly what they need. Feel free to provide your own "Good Answer™" any time.

Comment: And @jjr2000, thank you for mentioning `parseInt()`. I'll update my answer to include that as well. :-)

Comment: @jeff, apparently you haven't noticed *the questioner uses `parseInt()` in their code*. Anyway, if they really *make no mention of what they actually want to do with these values*, then the question is unclear and should be closed, not answered. Re: your last sentence, I *did* try to steer the questioner towards a possible solution in comments, as I usually do for trivial, no-research questions like this. I don't answer them, and I think it's for the best. Have a nice day.

Comment: I was assuming that the OP had simply used `parseInt()` because it was the only way they could figure out how to split out one of those values. Could I have also assumed that they wanted an integer as the result? Yep. But I didn't. Oh well. That's why I appreciate @jjr2000 's comment, which *improves* upon the answer, rather than crapping all over it. As far as I'm concerned, the OP asked a reasonable question and showed how they'd unsuccessfully attempted to solve it. It doesn't matter what they want to do with those values. They just wanted to know how to get at them.

Answer (score 1):

If the text is always "number / number", you can extract the last number like this:

```
lastNumber = +(x.split('/')[1].trim());
```

`split` creates an array, `[1]` returns the second member in that array, and `trim` removes the white-space around a string. Finally `+` in front of the expression converts the value to number.

Answer (score 0):

RegExes would be one option, but a more basic way would be like this:

```
var totalNum = parseInt(x.substr(x.indexOf('/') + 1));
var pageNum = parseInt(x);
```